# How to have AMP site working only for mobile and Desktop for normal desktop users

Tags: amp-html

We are pretty new to AMP setup and we are trying to move to AMP site only for mobile users.

We want our desktop site to be used as is for desktop user and when a mobile user search for that page it should give AMP page in search result.

My question is, is it the core behavior of AMP or do we need to have some kind of redirect setup based on screen size?

I know the  tag is used to define the amp and non-amp site on them but does that mean that when a user search that page in desktop google search he/she will get only AMP page in search result?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to create two different url one for desktop and another for mobile:

For example

Desktop Url : https://www.example.com/home.html

AMP Url : https://www.example.com/home-amp.html

**Now Make your page discoverable**

Add the following to the non-AMP page (Desktop) - in home.html file:

```
 <link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/home-amp.html">
```

And this to the AMP page - in home-amp.html file:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/home.html">
```

For more information [**click here**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/discovery)

Comment: Yes this i am aware but i was confused if searching in mobile or desktop will return amp site always but if this is not the case then we are good. Can u pls confirm?

Comment: search in mobile you will get amp site url on google, you can use user agent in desktop

Comment: Great! One more question can we simulate google search indexing for the amp site in test env, i mean how can we test it to be sure before going live?

Comment: you can test your page here https://search.google.com/test/amp and https://validator.ampproject.org/.

Comment: Awesome thanka alot. If this all helps I will mark to your answer!

Comment: Just make sure that your AMP pages are indexed properly in your Google search console.